Question about Amazon Elasticache and CloudWatch
My redis elasticache cluster has a service linked role but it still doesn’t send logs to cloudwatch. I tried to connect a policy to the log group but still no logs. I dont think i can create a role for elasticache. I dont know what to do. How would you solve this?
I verified service-linked role for ElastiCache, enabled log exports on Elasticache cluster, verified Cloudwatch log group, attached policy to the log group.
What am I missing here?
